# iOS - How to drag element during animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, drag-and-drop

i need to drag an element during an animation. The element fall from the top of the screen and i need the user can drag it wherever he want, even during animation
Thanks

Comment: How are you performing the animation?

Comment: With [UIView animateWithDuration:_DURATION_ animations:_BLOCK_]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the `UIView` block based animations, try using:

```
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

with the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option.

Comment: This doesn't work, i don't know why. I write this code : [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction & UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^ (void) {
        [ingredient setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 34, 45)];
    } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Completed");
    }];

Answer (score 1):

You can use the touchesBegan method to detect when the user touches the element.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch != nil && (touch.view == elementView))
        //do your stuff
}
```

Then set the element's position to the touch location, and remove the animation.

```
elementView.center = [touch locationInView:self.view];
[elementView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

This should work. Then you can use the similar touchesMoved method to update the position during the drag.

Comment: Yes, but this work if the element can be touched during animation!